# Previewing Audio .UPKs

Tags: gameaudio, udk, qc

I have no idea of this exists. But if it doesnt, it should.

Sometimes I want to double check audio in .upk package files that I make within the Unreal Editor. The ability to see the audio files and their respective cue files would be awesome.

Additionally, it would be awesome to preview cues that are in .upk files without having to open up the engine editor.

The benefits of this would be obvious:

- No UDK loading time
- No loading UPKs into the Content Browser / Project
- Quality Check audio packages quickly
- Quality Check cue DSP charts quickly

Anyone know if this is possible?

---